# MdilXapCompile.exe -- Windows Phone Device Deployment Error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, deployment, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to deploy my appo to my Lumia 930 so I can test it on something other than an emulator, but every time I hit F5 it basses the build but crashes on deplyment.

MIDLXapCompile log file:

```
CrossGen failed
Error processing assembly C:\Users\mrrey_000\Dropbox\Dev\Windows Store\AnimeWatcherXYZ EX Summer\AnimeWatcherXYZ.WindowsPhone\obj\ARM\Debug\MSIL\Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Display.winmd
Raw error code: 2148733978
```

I tried deleting the reference to the Microsoft Advertising SDK and applying i oce again, I've also tried to remove the previous version of the app from my device - didn't help.

And yeah, I'm deploying a `DEBUG` package, not `RELEASE`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using  'ADAL library' form nuget ?

Comment: No, I'm not using any Azure services anymore, but yeah, I had similar problems with them in the past now that I think about it